# How to export only new registry entries?

Tags: windows-xp

Some software I install creates various registry entries on installation.

The installation takes a really long time.

Once in a while I reinstall windows.

Instead of having to reinstall my software (which is stored on a separate drive), is there a way I can discover ONLY the registry keys that have been created after installation (of my software) and save it as a reg file, so that the next time I reinstall windows I can just update the registry by clicking on that file ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have a tool to do this: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

It is quite a complex tool for the beginner but there are some good usage tips on [How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/all/)

As a starter you can filter on Operations that begin with `Reg`:

[image]

Comment: Sweet! but my pc is tagged Windows-XP. That link you linked to says Process Monitor runs only on Windows Vista or higher...omg lolz windows so cwazy.

Comment: That would be because XP is now completely unsupported by Microsoft! And Vista will be the same next month.

Comment: You can get an older version which supports XP from here: http://www.oldapps.com/process_explorer.php the Registry functionality shouldn't have changed that much

Comment: You also REALLY ought to think about an upgrade to Win 7 at least!

Comment: I don't use Windows XP out of choice. I use it because I am forced to. For other development I use Win 7, 8 and 10. But XP is for legacy code.

Comment: ah, fair enough. Hopefully oldapps.com will provide a version which works